# Cannot run java file in VS code in Zorin OS

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, java-11

When I run Java -version command it shows:

```
openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.5+8 (build 17.0.5+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Still, when I open VS code, It shows me this [VS code Window error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p84St.png)

How to resolve this ??

I tried installing Multiple JDKs and still the error continues, I tried to look into extensions settings but can't get what to do

Also when i try to configure java runtime with command pallet it shows me this:

[Vs code window with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdXnt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following configuration to the **settings.json** to specify the jdk path

```json
    // Here is the Windows system as an example
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-17",
            "path": "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Eclipse Adoptium\\jdk-17.0.3.7-hotspot",
            "default": true
        },
    ],
```

More information can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_configure-runtime-for-projects).